# Plot ROC from multi-class from Weka prediction

Tags: python, python-3.x, weka, roc, auc

I am trying to plot ROC curve from the prediction which was obtained from Weka command prompt. It contains Actual, predicted, error and prediction column. How to plot from this in Python (or other Language).

[image: Example of sample data]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Weka, why don't you use its Explorer to display the ROC curve itself?

Rather than using the raw actual/predicted values, Weka's command-line can output the correctly computed data in a separate file (using the options `-threshold-file` and `-threshold-label`).

See the Weka wiki article on [ROC Curves](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/roc_curves/) for more details.